# Grunt+Bower: dependency to another local project

Tags: gruntjs, bower

I have two local Grunt+Bower-projects with typical `build` and `watch`/`serve` tasks:

- `Client` contains the client to be publicly released
- `AdminClient` is an extension to `client` intended for internal administration use

`AdminClient` should re-use `Client` code and build-result. `watch`/`serve` must behave transparently for any change in `Client` and `AdminClient`.

How can I do this with Grunt+Bower?

It is a basic problem solved in C# with project dependency and in java typically with maven [sub-modules](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the Client configuration in a separate file that you extend in the AdminClient.

```
var common = require("common.js");
...
grunt.initConfig(common.config);
```

Comment: Indeed it is a good solution for re-using the tasks of `Client`! I will try this way. I fear I will get some problems with the `watch` task: after a re-build of `Client`, I will need to cascade and re-build `AdminClient`... I will see...